# How do i convert date to specific date format using an momentjs library?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have the following date format:

```
29-Jan-2023 06.33.51.144 AM
```

I need to convert it to the following format using the moment.js library:

```
01/29/2023 06.33 AM
```

I used the following code ,

```
moment(date).format('DD/MMM/YYY HH:MM A' )
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you tried that code, and?

Comment: It is showing as invalid date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

> If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a moment.

```js
const formatted = moment('29-Jan-2023 06.33.51.144 AM', 'DD-MMM-YYYY HH.mm.ss.SSS a').format('DD/MMM/YYYY HH:MM A')

console.log(formatted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```